# How to simulate a click to open a tab after auto scroll

Tags: jscript, autoscroll

I have a problem , i have a script for mobile version of page that will scroll down the page to a specific div tag, it works fine but I would like the script to also open this section (open a tab) 
This is what i got so far

The script

```
   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhAnimatedScroll" visible="false" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var navHeight = $('#gecko-sub-navigation').outerHeight();
        var buffer = (navHeight * 2) + 70;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + '<%=SelectedPage%>').offset().top - buffer     }, 1000);
    </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

One of the sections of the page

```
   <section class="help_section">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link help_switch closed"> Box title </a>
    <div class="help_details">
        <div class="help_btm_msg"> some text </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The opening of the tab is triggered by click on anchor tag so the class changes from class="link help_switch closed" to class="link help_switch open" , is there any way to adjust the script so that it will change the class from closed to open or emulate the click ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jquery, you can simulate a mouseclick, or trigger a click on a certain element using the `trigger` function.

jQuery documentation:
[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

The idea is that you can first setup a click handler, and then call that click handler any time by triggering the "click" function in your code:

```
$( ".help_switch" ).on( "click", function() {

    alert("help_switch has been clicked, or triggered.");

    // now toggle the open/closed class
    var isOpen = !$(this).hasClass("closed");
    if(isOpen){
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $(this).addClass("closed");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("closed");
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
});

// trigger the "click" event on .help_switch when the page loads
// to show an example of how to call it:
$( ".help_switch" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Hope this helps.

You can see a working example of this code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cvkm7y3/3/, if you load this code in jsfiddle, then you can watch how the closed and open class toggles on your help_switch class as you click the "Box Title" link by "Inspect Element" in Chrome Developer Tools or your web inspector of choice.